# Android dual sim detection

Tags: android, dual-sim

I have MICROMAX A100 dual SIM android phone, In my app I am accessing SIM serial number, by default I am getting SIM serial number of SIM 1, How can I access the SIM 2 data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is a hardware implementation by manufacturer (Like some phones have internal and external storage). Default android API is not designed to accommodate all manufacturer imposed features. Though manufacturers are free to modify the android they distribute on their devices and implement new features. And usually manufacturers provide additional libraries for developers to exploit those features. So, Contact the manufacturer if they provide additional API for their devices.

Comment: Ok i got your point....Actually I am making a sim tracker app based on checking the sim serial number has been changed or not. So in case if they changes second Sim then My app wont work... :(:(:( :'(

Comment: @CautionContinues Think of it: whether some one opens the phone and physically swap the SIM, or user switches between dual SIM's, to system, it is always going to appear as a SIM change. So, on start-up, request user to register his all SIM cards with your app . Store all the allowed SIM data, then you can always detect when a SIM's NOT registered with your app is in use.

Comment: While registering I am taking his Sim serial (by default sim 1) and storing it into the shared preference and whenever cell phone reboots I am checking whether stored and current sim serial are same or not hence I am able to check the sim change. Let C what can get to fix it.

Comment: @CautionContinues Exactly, ask user if he wants to register more SIM's, if yes, user can switch to other SIM, and press _register this_ button on your App. Now you got both SIM's registered.

Comment: @CautionContinues : Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/14517338/840669 ?