# How to get the number of the second SIM card?

Tags: android

How to get the number of the second SIM card?

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.getLine1Number();
```

Returns the number of the first SIM card.

Comment: It seems there is no direct support for multi-SIM devices in the Android SDK. However, using Java reflection you may be able to get some information using the `TelephonyManager`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim for an idea.