# Android IMEI Confusion for "Dual Simcard Devices"

Tags: android

I am using below code to get the IMEI of the Android devices,

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
```

It is fine for the devices having a single sim active. If we apply the same code for the devices having two sim cards, then how can I get the `DeviceID` and tell whether I got SIM1 Id or SIM2 Id?

Comment: AFAIK You cnat tell you have got the ID of `SIM 1 or SIM 2`...

The above mentioned code will return the id of the `ACTIVE/DEFAULT SIM`

If you Know the in setting you can set the default actions of the SIM's... Answered on the basis of what I Observerd on `Micromax Canavas 2 (Dual Sim)`

Comment: You **can** get 2 different IMEIs in case of Dual SIM devices. Refer **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/840669 "this answer")** by [Pied Piper](http://stackoverflow.com/users/703851/pied-piper) to get 2 different IMEIs for dual SIM phones.

Answer (score 2):

IMEI number should be associated with the phone and not with the sim, so also in dual sim devices you should have only one IMEI number.

"The IMEI is only used for identifying the device" [...] "Instead, the subscriber is identified by transmission of an IMSI number, which is stored on a SIM card" - ref: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity)

---

EDIT:

Check the source code, maybe you can find some hint: [Source of Settings app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/5c879e48eddfe617125733f2be46854a0266a23b/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/Status.java)

Here a snippet of the "IMEI" part:

```
// NOTE "imei" is the "Device ID" since it represents
        // the IMEI in GSM and the MEID in CDMA
        if (mPhone.getPhoneName().equals("CDMA")) {
            setSummaryText(KEY_MEID_NUMBER, mPhone.getMeid());
            setSummaryText(KEY_MIN_NUMBER, mPhone.getCdmaMin());
            if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.config_msid_enable)) {
                findPreference(KEY_MIN_NUMBER).setTitle(R.string.status_msid_number);
            }
            setSummaryText(KEY_PRL_VERSION, mPhone.getCdmaPrlVersion());
            removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_IMEI_SV);

            if (mPhone.getLteOnCdmaMode() == PhoneConstants.LTE_ON_CDMA_TRUE) {
                // Show ICC ID and IMEI for LTE device
                setSummaryText(KEY_ICC_ID, mPhone.getIccSerialNumber());
                setSummaryText(KEY_IMEI, mPhone.getImei());
            } else {
                // device is not GSM/UMTS, do not display GSM/UMTS features
                // check Null in case no specified preference in overlay xml
                removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_IMEI);
                removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_ICC_ID);
            }
        } else {
            setSummaryText(KEY_IMEI, mPhone.getDeviceId());

            setSummaryText(KEY_IMEI_SV,
                    ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE))
                        .getDeviceSoftwareVersion());

            // device is not CDMA, do not display CDMA features
            // check Null in case no specified preference in overlay xml
            removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_PRL_VERSION);
            removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_MEID_NUMBER);
            removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_MIN_NUMBER);
            removePreferenceFromScreen(KEY_ICC_ID);

            // only show area info when SIM country is Brazil
            if ("br".equals(mTelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso())) {
                mShowLatestAreaInfo = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, If I gone to Settings in my android mobile , I can find two IMEI numbers ..How?

Comment: Probably that's the IMSI number, but unfortunately I've no dual-sim device to check it and no other clue on it.. : /

Comment: @user2462298 questions like these are best answered by reading the Android sources (for the Settings app of course, in this case).

Comment: Edited. And if you check the comment in the source: `// NOTE "imei" is the "Device ID"`. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

In Dual Sim Devices, they have two IMEI Numbers for each SIM Slots. both are static. First IMEI No. is for First Slot and Second No. is for Second Slot.