# Call logging with dual sim with operator

Tags: android, call

i want to get the call logs list with sim card operators for dual sim android [Mediatek + samsung processors]. i have searched a lot but havent got any support from mediatek or samsung for a dual sim API. I know google supports only single sim..But if the manufacturers can do it so can we..please help!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim maybe you can apply the same principle to fetch call log for dual sim

Comment: I am not sure haven't used dual sim android, is the call log recorded separately for each sim?

Comment: Not separately,but there is a value that mentions whether the call was made by which sim. [http://developer.mediatek.com/mre/en/question/6952] see the screenshots here