# Android Dual SIM LAC:CID:CSQ:Operator IMEI 2 reporting

Tags: android, cell, gsm, dual-sim

My testing phone is Samsung A3 with Android 5.0.2.

When SIM2 is inserted and slot 1 is empty

```
getNetworkOperator()
onSignalStrengthChanged()
onCellLocationChanged()
```

reports LAC, CID, CSQ & operator for SIM2.

When SIM1 is inserted, all data is for SIM1. 
Data for SIM2 is not reported.

What must I do to get LAC:CID:CSQ:OPER for both SIMs paralelly?

**EDIT**

Answer about LAC:CID:CSQ is in: [Android signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782191/android-signal-strength/32882832#32882832)

But how to get network operators for both SIMs?

**===  SUMMARY EDIT  WITH COMPLETE ANSWER  ===**

According to **@headuck** post in:
[Android signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782191/android-signal-strength/32882832#32882832)
where in class:

```
public class MultiSimListener extends PhoneStateListener
```

is signal strenghts listener:

```
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {}
```

to get current LAC:CID should be added:

```
public void  onCellLocationChanged (CellLocation cl){}
```

and to get network current operator (this may changed in roaming) with numeric, alpha short & alpha long values:

```
public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState){}
```

and in tm.listen must be added LISTEN_ values:

```
tm.listen(listener[subIdList[i]], 
     PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS 
    | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION
    | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
```

where **tm** is TelephonyManager instance.

**In addition** to get IMEI1, IMEI2, presence DualSIM, SIM's and roaming in both slots,
the ready to use is **TelephonyInfo** class in [Android : How to get SIM ID of both SIM in Dual SIM mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229623/android-how-to-get-sim-id-of-both-sim-in-dual-sim-mobile) **@Anand Makwana** post.

All this work pretty well for Android 5.0, I dont know how to 5.1.

In Android 4 MultiSimListener not working, but TelephonyInfo is OK.

Comment: Is there any useful information on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018565/dual-sim-android

Comment: I don't know, see my SUMMARY EDIT

Comment: You can try use `MultiSim` library:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/41544422/1665964