# how to find get mobile no and imei no using android apps and display in apps

Tags: android

**> how to find get mobile no and imei no using android apps.**

---

I am developing an app for a mobile carrier. First I wanted to find any of the things (IMSI, ICCID, IMEI, MSISDN) so that .

Now as a workaround I will ask the user to register his phone number with my app. But then again bad things will happen if user changes the SIM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

String imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
```

[Refer this For More Clear Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)

Hope this could Help

Comment: Love to help always :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following for getting mobile number and IMEI number

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)Your_Context getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but its not always reliable on for example non phone device. You will also need to add permision `"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"`.

Comment: i am new with android apps..  
 
this is very useful for me thank you very much..