# checking device is dual sim or not and getting signal strength for both sims

Tags: android

After a long time i researched for retrieving the signal strength of dual Sim. I want to know the phone is dual Sim or not. If it is dual Sim phone i need to know each and every Sim signal strength.

Please give me a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in android to detect dual sim functionality.  You can use **Java reflection** to detect dual sim. Please follow below link for more details

[Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)