# Failed to get Sim Card details (Sim Serial Number) for sim2 in Samsung Dual Android phone

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, telephonymanager, sim-card

I'm trying to get sim card details for sim 1 and sim 2 in a Samsung dual phone (Samsung Gt-S6802) , I am able to get details for sim 1 but for sim 2 I get a null value.

I'm using Java reflection method to get both Sim Serial numbers.

I used this tutorial [Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Kindly if you know any work around for this let me know.

Thanks

Comment: `http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/getting-phone-numberimei-number-and-sim-card-id-in-android/` this may help you

Comment: Does the two kind of card is the same and they can work together? I know there are some problems when getting a sim serival number of CDMA card. There is a link of(in Chinese) http://www.cnblogs.com/xiaowenji/archive/2011/01/11/1933087.html

Comment: @ДмитрийИвановичМенделеев the link you sent me doesn't work for dual sim phones , but thanks for sharing the link

Comment: @twlkyao I tried testing with a different Samsung dual phone ,with android version 4.0.3 it works, but for this particular device I am using it doesn't work it has android version 2.3 it returns null for sim 2 details.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still interested in knowing the answer, for API >= 22 only

```
// you may ignore TelephonyManager if you don't want to get the IMEI
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext());
List<SubscriptionInfo> subsList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subsList ) {
    // get IMEI
    int simSlotIndex = subscriptionInfo.getSimSlotIndex();
    String imei = telephonyManager.getImei(simSlotIndex);

    // get serial number
    String serialNumber = subscriptionInfo.getIccId();

    // get line number
    String lineNumber = subscriptionInfo.getNumber();
}
```