# Is it possible to get different IMEI in android dual SIM device using getDeviceId

Tags: android

I am using dual SIM mobile, while dialing `*#06#`, I am getting two IMEI numbers`(IMEI1 = ***973 & IMEI2 = ***980)`.

While trying with `telePhonyManager.getDeviceId()`, I am always getting `***973(IMEI1)`.

```
TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        textView.append("IMEI Number: " + mngr.getDeviceId());
```

In my application, I am going to use IMEI number as unique reference for user.

While searching regarding it, some site posted that `getDeviceId()` possible to return `***980(IMEI2)`.
My question is, in future is it possible `getDeviceId()` method to return  `***980(IMEI2)?`

Comment: maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **NO**, there is no foolproof way of writing code that will retrieve both IMEI numbers of a dual-SIM phone. The official AOSP supports only single SIM usage, and all devices that have dual-SIM feature have had their OS source code modified by the phone manufacturers.

If a phone has two SIM cards in both slots, then the IMEI number of the first slot is retrieved by default, and if a phone has only one SIM card in either slot, then the IMEI number of the occupied slot (first or second) is retrieved by default. This is the behavior I have observed on `Micromax` and `HTC` phones, but I suspect that this too is implementation dependent.

I would advise you to write your code so that it is not dependent on multiple SIMs'; preferably, IMEI number of a phone should not be used for anything as this will probably be removed in future versions of Android. iOS already prevents developers from accessing IMEI number.

There is [a post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim) where the author has used a very innovative technique - namely, reflection - to get the *names* of the methods for getting the second IMEI number on dual-SIM phones. Very interesting, but almost impossible to use in production code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have one doubt, colleague saying that, depends on network connection enable, you will get IMEI number is it? Ex:Net enabled in SIM one means will get IMEI1, if SIM two means get IMEI2?

Comment: yes precisely ... i don't think it depends on net connectivity ... if there is one sim card in either slot, then you get IMEI of that slot ... but i advise you to test my theory and your colleague's theory also ... and let me know the result!

Comment: @SathishKumar: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: I checked those scenario in Sony Xperia M Dual SIM, both not happening. Always I am getting IMEI of first SIM slot.

Comment: hmm ... that means that even this is device-dependent. I have based my answer on my experience with Micromax and HTC phones

Comment: oh OK  Thanks, if possible let i try with those devices.

Answer (score 0):

With API Level 23, Android enabled [getDeviceId(slotIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId(int)) to get different IMEI/MEID for dual sim phones. To get number of slots, call [getPhoneCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneCount()).