# Check whether one or two SIMs are inserted into the android device

Tags: android, telephonymanager

`

// Call on clicking the call menu

```
private void makeCall(int correct) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

    String imsiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM1();
    String imsiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM2();

    boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
    boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

    boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();

    Toast.makeText(
            NavigationDrawer.this,
            " IME1 : " + imsiSIM1 + "\n" + " IME2 : " + imsiSIM2 + "\n"
                    + " IS DUAL SIM : " + isDualSIM + "\n"
                    + " IS SIM1 READY : " + isSIM1Ready + "\n"
                    + " IS SIM2 READY : " + isSIM2Ready + "\n",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (!isDualSIM) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "9841967608"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (isDualSIM) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(NavigationDrawer.this)
                .setMessage("Choose the SIM")

                .setPositiveButton("SIM2",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                                        + "9841967608"));
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

                                intent.putExtra("simSlot", 1);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("SIM1",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                                        + "9841967608"));
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

                                intent.putExtra("simSlot", 0);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })

                .show();
    }
}`
```

I am doing a project where I have to check whether the device contains one or two SIM inserted into it. I only need to know the no of SIMs inside the device not the IMEI no. or IMSI no. I tried the the link [Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim?lq=1) but it does not work in my Samsung Duos device.How can my problem be solved?Help!

In my toolbar there is a call menu item which on clicking should check whether the device has one or two SIMs inserted. If the device contains one SIM, call should be made directly using the default SIM, else the alert dialog box should be shown with the options to choose the SIM(SIM1 or SIM2) with which you want to call the number. I have used the TelephonyInfo.java class provided in the link above.

Comment: I used toast instaed of the textview to test the given link and it didnt give the IMEI no of both SIM, instead gave IMEI of only one SIM, the default one.

Comment: please post  your code

Comment: Any information regarding SIM #2 (or any other then default SIM) is purely manufacturer dependent. Android does not provide APIs for multi-SIM facility. Android apis only support default SIM Card slot.

Comment: I just need to know if the second SIM is inserted or not. I dont reqiure to know about the IMEI or other information about the SIM, just in boolean form of whether the second SIM is there or not.Can it be done?@MSS

Comment: dude ,The current Android platform does not have support for multiple SIMs(dual). A device with such support has been customized for this

Comment: Then I guess i have to stop searching for the solution. Thanks for your concern @MSS.