# getting Blank Value when using telephonyManager.getLine1Number() for getting my sim number

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am using Moto e for getting my sim number by telephoney methode telephonyManager.getLine1Number() . but it retrieves blank .

**can anybody have any idea about other ways to find sim number/numbers?**

Comment: Is it a dual sim phone? If yes, does it have a simcard in both slots?

Comment: Yes @AkhilCherianVerghese   
 this is ....  and it have simcards in both slots.

Comment: please let me know if the updated answer works.

Answer (score 1):

the  getLine1Number() return phone number if we have number listed in About Phone section in Settings. Otherwise we can't and I also didn't find any other options till now .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Moto E is a dual sim phone. Android didn't support that before 5.1 I believe, so that call won't work (even if you have simcards in both slots).

To get the number of a dual sim phone, please follow this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/1642200