# How to get IMEI of all SIM cards by using Lollipop MR1 Multiple SIM support (via SubscriptionManager)?

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop, dual-sim

As [announced](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html?utm_campaign=lollipop-51-315&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog#multisim) for Lollipop MR1, [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) and its [SubscriptionInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo.html) provide lots of information about all (active) SIMs, but I'm missing their IMEIs.

I get info about SIMs like this:

```
    SubscriptionManager sm = SubscriptionManager.from(context);

    List<SubscriptionInfo> sil = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
    if (sil != null) {
      for (SubscriptionInfo subInfo : sil) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SubInfo:" + subInfo);
      }
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "SubInfo: list is null");
    }
```

Am I missing something or can we still only get the IMEI (only of the 1st SIM card) via `telephonyManager.getDeviceId()`?

Answer (score 2):

The method

```
public String getDeviceId(int slotId)
```

is available under `TelephonyManager` in API 23. `slotId` is just a number from 0 to the number of SIMs - 1.

In API 22, the same method exists but is hidden. You need to use reflection to call it.

Comment: how i can get device id in api 19

Answer (score 0):

The [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) is used to identify the device, not the SIMs.So yes, you can only get the IMEI through `telephonyManager.getDeviceId()`.

**UPDATE**: So it turns out I was wrong and a device can have an IMEI for each SIM card. I've found this answer in StackOverflow that can help you.

[Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889)

Comment: Possibly you never had a Dual SIM phone? At least check these for reference: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_ccAy-n4Tq0/U5zAjZvmk6I/AAAAAAAADss/6mpzfPfMuhw/s1600/Screenshot_2014-06-15-02-53-24.png, http://www.techsng.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/new-IMEI-Numbers1.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qiuh.jpg .

Comment: @Saran I'am surprised, it really can have more than one IMEI. I'll update my answer then.