# How can I get the IMEI numbers for a dual SIM phone

Tags: android

The dual SIM phones have two `IMEI` numbers. When I use the `getDeviceId()`, it can gets the one of the `IMEI` numbers. While we can get the all `IMEI` numbers using the `*#06#` code. are there a way to get the all the `IMEI` numbers in the a dual SIM phones in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)