# Intent.ACTION_CALL is not working when a pop up window opens to select my account

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call, android-dialer

I am implementing an Android app that will allow users to purchase something by dialing a number from my app pressing a button. In single SIM devices it works nicely, but in dual sim devices, when I run my app and click on the "Purchase Button" a popup window automatically opens to ask me which SIM I want to use to dial (I didn't have to write code for this action, It automatically done by my device. Also when I normally call a friend using the default Phone App of my device this pop up window opens automatically to ask me which Sim I wanna use to dial and after selecting a sim it starts calling), but in case of my app after selecting an SIM , It doesn't work, It doesn't start dialing. But It starts dialing in single sim devices.

I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>` correctly and my code works nicely on single SIM devices.

So what's the problem? Why it's not working on dual Sim devices?

My code:

```
Button button1maina = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);

        button1maina.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "*566%23"));;
         startActivity(callIntent);  

        }
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

You must specify the simcard to start the intent activity. First of all, check if the phone is Dual Sim with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/3743245

After that, try to ask the user which simcard he/she will use and pass that info like this:

```
intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 0); //For sim 1
```

or

```
intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1); //For sim 2
```

and if doesn't work try this:

```
intent.putExtra("simSlot", 0); //For sim 1
```

or

```
intent.putExtra("simSlot", 1); //For sim 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write these two line of code rest of thee this will automatically done by the system hear you don't worry about single/dual SIM

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:"+"999999");
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
```

refer official guide for more detail http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html