# Making a call from a dual sim android device using adb

Tags: android, adb, dual-sim

I am trying to make a call from a specific sim on a dual sim phone (SIM 0 and SIM 1) using adb and I can't figure out how to direct the call to that particular sim slot.
So far, I have tried making a call using the following command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:XXXXXXXXXX
```

This works fine, but it always calls using SIM 0.

I tried using radiooptions as:

```
adb shell radiooptions
```

but it turns out, radiooptions is not supported on this particular device.

```
/system/bin/sh: radiooptions: not found
```

I did try it on another device, which is not dual sim, and radiooptions seems to work on that. That was the whole reason I was trying out radiooptions in the first place because it has a very clear cut implementation for selecting specific sim cards.

Anyways, I found the following questions for dual sim android phones, but they are not adb based. they are all Java questions.

[Make call using a specified SIM in a Dual SIM Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524476/make-call-using-a-specified-sim-in-a-dual-sim-device)

[Call from second sim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231962/call-from-second-sim)

They seem to help and give some clues as to how it can be done,especially this one:

[SO Answer for changing SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32615246/6866819)

This is very close to what I need, but I don't know how to convert this into a command prompt friendly code.

The method "intent" used in the above links has a documentation here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Multi sim android official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIM Card is just a container. The name of the entity being used by the phone to register with the network and to make calls is *SubscriberID*. A single SIM Card may contain multiple *SubscriberIDs*.

So instead of asking how to *make a call from another SIM Card* you should be asking how to *make a call using SubscriberID other than the default one* - whether this other *SubscriberID* is stored on the same or another SIM Card is mostly irrelevant.

I do not know if there is a way to specify a different *SubscriberID* for a single call. But you should be fine with setting a new default *SubscriberID* before the call and then reverting it back afterwards.

To find out the current ID value run:

```
adb shell settings get global multi_sim_voice_call
```

Then change the active Subscriber via UI and run the command again to get another ID.

Use this command to switch to the appropriate ID before calling:

```
adb shell settings put global multi_sim_voice_call <ID>
```

To change `data` call settings - use `multi_sim_data_call` instead of `multi_sim_voice_call`.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it and it works very well. And thanks for the explanation. I didn't know about a lot of this stuff. Do you know where i could find the documentation for this? for example, i also wanted to try multi sim sms, and after googling around, i found "multi_sim_sms" just like "multi_sim_voice_call", but i couldn't find any official documentation. if you could give me a link, that would be much appreciated. Thanks again.:-)