# Change data subscription (SIM card) in multi-sim Android phone

Tags: android, sim-card

I have a dual-sim Android phone and during the morning I use one of the SIM cards for the data connection, and during the evening I use the other one. It's a pita to manually switch from one card to the other twice every day, so I thought I could create a simple app that does the switching at a given time.

I've been reading and looks like starting at version 5.1 of Android's API, theres a [`SubscriptionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getDefaultDataSubscriptionId()) class which offers info about current subscriptions (data, voice, sms, etc), but as far as I've seen there're a lot of `get` methods but no `setters` anywhere.

Does the Android API offer a way of setting the SIM card used in the data connection? I guess it does, because otherwise it wouldn't be possible to change it from the settings panel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43670737/1778421