# Get SIM serial number or a unique ID

Tags: android

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/3770134) to detect if or not my phone is Dual Sim. It works fine there but I am unable to use `.getSimSerialNumber();` in this method. It gives me the IMEI number of both the Sim slots. In fact, whatever I use `.getSimSerialNumber(); .getDeviceId(); .getSubscriberId(); .getLine1Number();` I get IMEI only and, the issue is for all my devices; Nexus, QMobile, Samsung, Huawei; I am able to check this as the IMEI is written with the slots.

It worked fine on Eclipse and after I installed Android Studio. I don't know what is causing the problem now. Can anyone help? Is there any other way to get a unique Sim ID?

I need it to detect my Sim card on a Web Server.

Comment: Most of the market I am targeting is Android 2.4 and above so I can't use the API provided by Android for Dual Sim. I using the same java reflection technique to send messages via Dual Sim and, that is still working.