# Can I find MCC + MNC of network providers for muti sims

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

For example I have a dual sim mobile with Airtel and Vodafone sims in it. I would like to know Can we get MCC and MNC of both network providers.

I know that

> Using [getPhoneCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneCount()) We can know, how many sims a device has.
>   Using [getNetworkOperator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperator()) we can get MCC+MNC of active network operator.

Answer (score -1):

It was not as easy before, but After **Lolipop** version you can do this.
Here is my Code:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                SubscriptionManager subManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
                if (subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() >= 1) {
                    List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList;
                    subscriptionInfoList=subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
                    String carrierName = subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getCarrierName().toString();
                    int mccSlot1 = subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getMcc();
                    int mncSlot1 = subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getMnc();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sim slot 1 " + mccSlot1 + " " + mncSlot1 + "Name"+carrierName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String carrierName2 = subscriptionInfoList.get(1).getCarrierName().toString();
                    int mccSlot2 = subscriptionInfoList.get(1).getMcc();
                    int mncSlot2 = subscriptionInfoList.get(1).getMnc();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sim slot 2 " + mccSlot2 + " " + mncSlot2+"Name"+carrierName2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (telephonyManager == null) {
                    return;
                }
                String mCCMncCode = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
                String mccCode = null;
                String mncCode = null;
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mCCMncCode)) {
                    return;
                }

                final int MNC_CODE_LENGTH = 3;
                if (mCCMncCode.length() >= MNC_CODE_LENGTH) {
                    mccCode = mCCMncCode.substring(0, MNC_CODE_LENGTH);
                }

                if (mCCMncCode.length() > MNC_CODE_LENGTH) {
                    mncCode = mCCMncCode.substring(MNC_CODE_LENGTH);
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lower than API 22 " + mccCode + " " + mncCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
```

Just Add this code in your on create method after giving permission.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Note: If Your testing this on latest android versions like marshmellow,nougat & oreo then you have to give `checkselfpermission` (Run time Permissions). 
For Dual Sim checking, View this : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)