# How do I know if the mobile device is dual-sim?

Tags: android, sms, dual-sim

I have an sms sending application and the sms must be sent from a specific phone number. For dual sim smartphones, the sms is sent by sim which is in slot one by default.

I want to check if the mobile device supports is dual sim supported and if so ask the user from which sim to send sms.

Comment: It is already asked. Check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)

Comment: i had already gone through the link but the didnt work out on samsung eon which is single sim but the dual sim boolean appeared as true.