# Android Dual Sim Get Sim Detais of Both the SIM

Tags: android

I am Working with a project in to that i need to get all the sim details of both the SIMs like  `getSimCountryIso`,`getSubscriberId`,`getLine1Number` ,`getSimSerialNumber` curently i am able to get all these details of SIM 1 But

**not able to get for second SIM how to get it's information also?**

Kindly Help me out..

I get to know that **Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK.** But any alternet way from there i can know these things? 
Atleast SIM Unique ID.

I also need to know when any of the SIM changed... so this can identify by SIMID
Thanks,

Comment: You will find a lot of info here: [Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK.

[Android 5.1 onwards](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) Multiple Sim API