# Check total number of SIM slot in mobile

Tags: android, dual-sim

After a lot of research, I know the information about total active SIM.
But I want to know about  **total number of SIM slot**  (SIM active or not) are in mobile.
So my question is,

Can we detect that the phone has single SIM or multi SIMs?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for your response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need this method. [SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax())

Comment: Thanks.. Finally i got the solution its working fine.

Comment: Generally speaking, methods suggesting reflections and such rely on the SIM being present in the slot. So far getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax() on the other hand is the only one which returns the proper value, for instance 2 even when 1 SIM only is present.

Comment: While getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax() requires API 22, since API 23 they added getPhoneCount() which actually mention the dual sim functionality in the docs [1].

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneCount()