# How to get imsi number list from android dual sim device?

Tags: android, dual-sim

I want to get list of imsi number(both sim card imsi number list) from dual sim card android device.
i have used TelephonyManager to get imsi number but its returning only primary sim card imsi number.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim

Comment: duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i tried solution mentioned by you in past,
it will return only primary sims IMSI number not both sim cards IMSI number.

Comment: which device do u have

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar also their is no getSubscriberId(int) method below api 22 in android to get 2nd sim IMSI number.

Comment: getSubscriberId(int) added in 23

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i am using Moto G2 , Sumsung , letv 1s.

Comment: thanx i have also will try my best just wait

Comment: yes i tested  getSubscriberId(int) in marshmallow device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue is being resolved in lollipop.
Check android subscription manager

Comment: Doesn't seem like it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html
does not contain reference to IMSI.

Comment: No method to retrieve IMSI in SubscriptionManager