# Get all SIM phone numbers

Tags: android

Is it possible to get all SIM numbers (if dual SIM) from phone programmatically? And how?

I know there's a way to [check if the phone is dual sim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/4673764). But I didn't find information how can I exctract actually those numbers.

There's a method to get phone number but it doesn't work for dual sim:

```
 TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String phone = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: not possible for some operators because sim numbers are not stored in sim cards. we can only get sim serial numbers.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, that's sad.. Anyway thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get phone number with telephonymanager class because some sim manufacturer companies does not provide sim number  on sim card as described in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278/6448399