# get serial number of both sims in API-19

Tags: android

I am using `TelephonyManager` to get sim's serial number, but I want to get serial number of both the sims if the device is dual sim. I know I can do this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim) but that method is too complex. So the question is that is there any simpler method? My device's Android Version is KitKat (API-19).

Comment: Just copy past the whole class and use it.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin Can you please tell how can I get Serial Number of both the sims using that example?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking for help, I'll reformulate what's in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/3503855).

1. Create a new `class` `public final class TelephonyInfo`.
2. Copy/Past the code found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/3503855).
3. Get an instance of the `TelephonyInfo class` and use it.

## How to get an instance?

```
// From an Activity, a Service...
TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);
```

## How to get both IMSIs?

```
// Check if the phone supports two SIM cards
if (telephonyInfo.isDualSIM()) {
    // Check if the first SIM is ready
    if (telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready()) {
        String imsiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM1();
    }
    // Check if the second SIM is ready
    if (telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready()) {
        String imsiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM2();
    }
}
```

Check the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/3503855), It's pretty well written.