# How to check if Device has 2 Sim Cards Inserted or 1 Sim Card and how to get path of both Sim - Android

Tags: java, android

```
private fun addContactToSim(number:String,name:String) {
   try {        
      val simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn")
      val values = ContentValues()
      values.put("number", number)
      values.put("tag", name)
      context.getContentResolver().insert(simUri, values)
   }
   catch (e:Exception)
   {
      e.printStackTrace()
   }
}
```

This is my Code. I am trying to create a contact. I want save contact in selected sim. If the user clicks on "save contact" then the app should ask if user wants to save it in 'SIM1' or 'SIM2' . Then when the user selects a SIM then it should save the contact in the appropriate sim.

But i don't know how to check if the phone has dual sim and how I will get path of sim.

Please help me.

Comment: Maybe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim) will help .

Comment: but  phone will not have sim then also it will show i want to check how many sim insterted

Comment: i updated Question @ADM