# Accessing both dual SIM cards

Tags: android, dual-sim

I'm new to Android and programming so I have been working on an app that can send USSD requests and sending calls and messages so far everything is working just fine. But the main issue is when I deployed it to a dual SIM phone it just reads the first one and completely ignores the second one .
How can I send requests from both SIM cards and know which sim is in number and which sim is  in two ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if your  API level is >22 ie marshmallow or higher, you can check for multiple SIMs using SubscriptionManager's method getActiveSubscriptionInfoList(). getDefaultDataSubscriptionId() would tell you what sim is active. More details on [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29).

Here is a [better answer to help you check whether the phone is dual sim and also device specific issues(Samsung/karbonn etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim?rq=1)